# When providing training examples for hashtags should I provide numeric as well as alphabetic?

Tags: bixby

I am training Bixby to recognize hashtags and do something different if an utterance begins with a hashtag than if it begins with something else. So far I have provided training examples in the format

> hashtag word
>
> hashtag word word
>
> hashtag word word word

Should I also provide examples in formats like

> hashtag number word word

For example,

`hashtag 420 From Home`

Another way of stating this is that I am asking does the training engine treat "words", numbers, and alphanumeric strings as being of equal weight when generating rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, your training should include representative samples of what you expect the user to say. But it is more important to get the pattern of the utterance correct.

The following utterances in your training will inform Bixby to expect 1, 2, or many words after hashtag.

- hashtag w1
- hashtag w1 w2
- hashtag w1 w2 w3

w1, w2, w3 can be either "alphanumeric" or words or numbers.